# TCP C client doesn't send but telnet to the server does

Tags: c, tcp

I have made a simple server that will print to the terminal when a message has been received along with the message. The client I made just sends the message (doesn’t receive) when I telnet and send messages to the server it works great and prints exactly what I sent. However when I write the C Client code found below its as if nothing is sent.

here is my compile output for the code below with -wall -wextra -pedantic

```
  ./client.c: In function ‘main’:
./client.c:17:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bzero’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
./client.c:19:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_addr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
./client.c:28:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
./client.c:28:41: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
./client.c:22:8: warning: unused variable ‘val’ [-Wunused-variable]
./client.c:10:15: warning: unused variable ‘n’ [-Wunused-variable]
./client.c:8:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
./client.c:8:26: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
soup@soup-XPS-8300:/home/c_dev/p2pcrypt_server/v0.1.0/src/tool_tests/libev
```

-

```
/* Sample TCP client */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
   char * sendline;
   sendline = "hello";

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(8018);

    int connect_status = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("%d\n", connect_status);

    int send_status = send(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0);
    printf("%d\n", send_status);

    printf("END\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Updated code
Connect returns "0" (success) and send returns "5" (i think thats how many successfull characters it sent)

Comment: Check the return value of `connect`.

Comment: `char sendline = "..."`? That's no string!

Comment: Perhaps you need to send a newline (`\r\n`) as well? (but also see Joachim's comment)

Comment: `sizeof(sendline)+1` will be one of the next problems.  Assuming you fix sendline you probably want `strlen(sendline)` because there's no point in sending the terminating \0

Comment: Compile with warning flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Always check what functions return and / or set of errors and status-codes. Then run with e.g. `valgrind` (+ add `-g` to compile flags.). Doing this you'll  go a long way in catching and tracking errors. Next step would be `-ggdb`  and run with `gdb`.

Comment: Ok... did you try fixing the warnings before asking here?

Comment: I tried \r\n aswell that dosen't seem to make the response any better. I'm going to try to get the send() return value as well but i'm pretty sure last time i checked it said success

Comment: oh wait now send returns -1.

Comment: How do i check for the specific send error? the manual page for that function is confusing on how to accomplish this: http://linux.die.net/man/2/send

Comment: You have to send something as a terminator, else server will not respond.  If the server protocol is telnet-like, then @JanDvorak is probably correct - add a \r\n, (and, of course, fix the sizeof/strlen issue).

Comment: You still haven't fixed the `char sendline` and that's a pretty deadly problem!

Comment: @fvu Not to mention that if using a pointer for the variable then `sizeof(sendline)` will be the size of the _pointer_ not the string.

Comment: Oh, with all the other issues, I didn't spot the missing & issue.

Comment: Closevoting as too localised. There are multiple issues, meaning that this question will only benefit the asker.

Comment: @jaochim pileborg I've tried strlen already... still working on trying out the other suggestions still

Comment: Checking for errors is _very_ simple: Almost all system calls (like `connect` and `send`) returns `-1` on error. You then need to check the global variable `errno`. A printable string can be had via the [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) function.

Comment: @Jan dvorak the question should benefit all this is a top ranking C example on google.

Comment: You have some more immediate fix of the code. The warnings given by gcc is not simply *noise*. `sendline` is one (as gives the first warning and the one next to last). Missing headers is another.  E.g. `man bzero`, `man inet_addr`.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot bzero is deprecated i'll change that to memset why did you mention inet_addr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the successfully working code on my end it seems the \r\n was needed and all the great suggestions that was pointed out. Thanks mates!

```
/* Sample TCP client */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
   char * sendline;
   sendline = "hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellolohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellolohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellolohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellolo\r\n";

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(8018);

    int connect_status = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("%d\n", connect_status);

    int send_status = send(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0);
    printf("%d\n", send_status);

    printf("END\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that you still haven't corrected the header file issues (ie, you are still receiving warnings about implicit declarations).  Don't be fooled by the fact that it works now, implicit declaration issues WILL come back some day and give you a hard time.  Learn to fix warnings right away, systematically.

Comment: Do you have a solution I don't know what headers are required for the warnings you are talking about, cheers mate!

Comment: `man strlen` and `man bzero` either on your system or in google.  The "Synopsis" paragraph of a manpage will always show the `#include` you need.  Also, as already pointed out by others (and the relevant [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero), bzero is a deprecated function, new programs should use its replacement [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

Comment: This made me think of you: [implicit declaration.](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_19.html) A nice example of **why** you should heed warnings. I'd recommend you read the entire book. It is short but very informative and plain. Index: [An Introduction to GCC](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for thinking of me and being the first one for me to provide evidence of behind the reasoning of this. Cheers!